# PHP Cache Lite PEAR

Tags: php, pear

please is there someone who knows how to install and use PEAR Cache Lite?
I try to make this little code but it returned an error:

Class 'PEAR' not found in `/var/www/vhosts...../Cache/Lite.php`

knowing that I have pear install on my dedicated server (Kernel red hat kimsufi)

```
// on fait appel a notre librairie PEAR
set_include_path(get_include_path() . "usr/share/pear");

// On charge Cache_Lite
require_once('../Cache/Lite/Output.php');

// On fixe un identifiant pour la page
$id = 'index.php';

// On définit quelques options :
// - le répertoire où seront stockés les fichiers de cache
// - la durée de vie du cache (ici 30 secondes)
$options = array('cacheDir' => '/tmp/','lifeTime' => 30);
// On crée un objet Cache_Lite_Output avec les options précédentes
$Cache_Lite_Output = new Cache_Lite_Output($options);
// Si la page n'est pas en cache...
echo "bonjour";
if (!($Cache_Lite_Output->start($id)))
{
  // ... alors on lance le script original

// marque la fin du script original
  $Cache_Lite_Output->end();
}
```

cordially.

Comment: See the "edit" link if you care to translate the French comments into English. And see the links to the formatting help that you will find in the right column then, and by pressing the question mark above the editor.

Answer (score 2):

`PEAR` is a dependency of `Cache_Lite`. How did you go about installing `Cache_Lite`? Did you just unpack it into your directory, or did you actually install it using the PEAR installer (i.e. `pear install Cache_Lite` from the command line). This is the correct approach for installing PEAR packages.

It looks like you may be setting your include path incorrectly. Try it with the following:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . "/usr/share/pear");
```

Note the include path separator is include, as well as `/` before `usr`.

Comment: Yes, I just unpack Cache_lite into my directory(www/httpdocs/Cache).
I do not know how to install from the command line!
I use SSH Secure shell Logiciel

Comment: To install from the command line, use `pear install Config_Lite`. If you can't do this, follow the instructions for shared install at http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.shared.php

Comment: So i try this pear install Config_Lite but it returns an error: 
Failed to download pear/Config_Lite within preferred state "stable", latest release is version 0.1.1, stability "beta", use "channel://pear.php.net/Config_Lite-0.1.1" to install
install failed

Comment: `pear install Cache_Lite` should do the trick. (Sorry, I put wrong package name :)